# Code Hints with JSTL in Netbeans

Tags: java, spring, jsp, netbeans, jstl

Is it possible to get code "hints" or code "completion" with JSTL in Netbeans?

I'm using Spring with JSPs as the View so there is really no way for the JSP to intuitively know what's on the pageContext. Is there a way to document or let netbeans know what type a model attribute is? This can be done with JavaScript in Netbeans so I wondered if it could also be done with JSP.

Example:

POJO

```
public class Person {
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/person")
public void person(Model model) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setFname("John");
    person.setLname("Smith");
    model.addAttribute("person", person);
}
```

JSP, person.jsp

```
Hello there, ${person.<ctrl-space>
```

At this point I want to be able to have Netbeans tell me what properties are available to `${person}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans isn't that intelligent. [IntelliJ is](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/screenshots/80/mvcAttributesCompletion.gif).

Comment: No, the community edition is only for Java SE. The ultimate edition is for Java EE and -among others- Spring MVC.

Comment: Thanks. I've always been a fan of IntelliJ. But this is for personal use so I'd have to pony up the capital myself. This isn't a deal breaker with Netbeans, only an annoyance. How do you like the Spring support?

Comment: I don't use Spring, so I can't tell much about it.

Comment: Although it doesn't technically answer my question (I don't wish to change IDEs at this point) it does answer by omission. I'll live without until Netbeans supports it or I fork over the cash for IntelliJ.

Comment: The answer just boils down to "no". We can't make a "yes" of this.